# php form data send to two different action

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a form, i want to send form data to two different action, can I do that in php

Comment: duplicate of [Two different actions on form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384819/two-different-actions-on-form-submit)

Comment: This issue has been discussed a million times. Did you look at the related questions before posting this? The one above this even comes up not that far down the list...

Comment: Hmm, most everyone said no, but the question "Can I do that in PHP?" is a yes, you can do that in PHP (but not in HTML). Just send the POST data to whatever two (or more) functions need to use the data.

Comment: Also duplicate of [PHP - HTML form two possible actions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086073/php-html-form-two-possible-actions)

Answer (score 1):

`No it's not possible` to send form data to two different actions simultaneously  (you can send form data by calling other method from the action called in the form ) `using PHP or any other programming langauage`

Comment: Using bold makes it stand out more than putting it in a code block (which it doesn't belong in)...

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way would be something like this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'action1':
             // do something
        break;
        case 'action2':
             // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Where you would have a hidden input in your form, which would contain type of the action you want to do. Then after the form is submited, you switch the action and do what you need.

The only other way, without PHP, would be to use AJAX as many of the answers in related questions suggest.

Answer (score 0):

No that is impossible because how would the browser know which page to send the user to (that is all an action is).

However, you could have it post to a PHP page that then fires the form submit to two separate actions (only makes sense for different webapps - if it's the same app could just pass to a function call).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! Your HTML form:

```
<form  name="Form1"  method="post">
<input name="username" value="ramiz" type="username">
<input name="password" value="0" type="hidden">
<input name="url" value="http://google.com" type="hidden">
<button onclick="open_win();send1();send2();closepopup();javascript:timedRefresh(5000);" name="send">Send </button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function open_win()
{mywindow1=window.open('','popup1','width=400,height=100');
mywindow2=window.open('','popup2','width=400,height=100');}function send1()
{document.Form1.action = "http://firstaction.php";
document.Form1.target = 'popup1';
document.Form1.submit(); }
function send2()
{document.Form1.action = "http://secondaction.php"
document.Form1.target = 'popup2';
document.Form1.submit(); }
function closepopup ({setTimeout('mywindow1.close();',5000);setTimeout('mywindow2.close();',5000);}
```

Details: When you click the submit button it opens two small popup windows, sends data to two different actions in those windows and then closes the popup windows in 5 seconds.

You can use iframes instead of popup windows and hide them using `display:none`. You have to set target to your iframe name.