# Send html form parameters to two django views

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, django-forms, django-views

I have parameters to be sent to two views in `views.py`, I can't (or don't know how to) merge these two because one need to be separated to generate plot image [like this one](http://www.eriksmistad.no/making-charts-and-outputing-them-as-images-to-the-browser-in-django/), is there any possibilities I could send the parameters to two views simultaneously or is it possible to merge these two views? Thanks in advance

My urls.py be like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

import survat.survatapp.views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static  

urlpatterns = patterns('survat.survatapp.views',
    url(r'^list/$', 'listindex', name='list'),
    url(r'^graph.png$', 'showimage'),
)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And my views.py be like

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from survat.survatapp.models import Document
from survat.survatapp.forms import DocumentForm

from survat.survatapp.modules.survat_core import printall
from survat.survatapp.modules.survat_core2 import printcox
from django.http import HttpResponse

import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import lifelines
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter,AalenAdditiveFitter

from django.http import HttpResponse
from matplotlib import pylab
from pylab import *
import PIL, PIL.Image, StringIO

def listindex(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            # ert= form.cleaned_data['aalenMember']
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('survat.survatapp.views.listindex'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    def delete_matrix():
        documents = Document.objects.all()
        for document in documents:
            document.delete()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        tempCox = []
        tempAalen = []
        timeColumn = request.POST.get('timeColumn', '')
        tempCox.append(timeColumn)
        tempAalen.append(timeColumn)
        eventColumn = request.POST.get('eventColumn', '')
        tempCox.append(eventColumn)
        tempAalen.append(eventColumn)
        coxMember = request.POST.get('coxMember', '')
        aalenMember = request.POST.get('aalenMember', '')
        coxMemberI = int(float(coxMember))
        aalenMemberI = int(float(aalenMember))
        coxCovariate = []
        aalenCovariate = []
        for j in range(1,coxMemberI):
            coxCovariate.append(request.POST.get('coxCovariate'+str(j), ''))
            tempCox.append(request.POST.get('coxCovariate'+str(j), ''))
        for k in range(1,aalenMemberI):
            aalenCovariate.append(request.POST.get('aalenCovariate'+str(k), ''))
            tempAalen.append(request.POST.get('aalenCovariate'+str(k), ''))
        ert = request.POST.get('coxMember', '')
        ert = str(type(int(float(ert))))
    else:
        tempCox = []
        tempAalen = []
        ert = "niji"
        timeColumn = "niji"
        eventColumn = "niji"
        coxMember = "niji"
        aalenMember = "niji"
        coxMemberI = "niji"
        aalenMemberI = "niji"
        coxCovariate = []
        aalenCovariate = []
        for j in range(1,20):
            coxCovariate.append ("niji")
        for k in range(1,20):
            aalenCovariate.append ("niji")

    asdf=printcox('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf','rx')
    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'survatapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'ert':ert, 'wer':tempAalen,'asdf':asdf},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )


def showimage(request):

    def printaalen(*args):
        module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # get current directory
        file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'prostate1.csv')
        prostate_dataset=pd.read_csv(file_path)
        # prostate_dataset=pd.read_csv(args[0])
        prostate_dataset=prostate_dataset[list(args[1:])]
        pdplot=prostate_dataset[list(args[3:])]
        for x in prostate_dataset:
            if (prostate_dataset[x].dtype=="object"):
                cat=pd.Series(list(prostate_dataset[x]))
                for y in pd.unique(cat):
                    prostate_dataset[x+'.'+y]=pd.get_dummies(cat)[y]
                prostate_dataset.drop(x, axis=1, inplace=True)

            else:
                pass

        aaf=AalenAdditiveFitter(fit_intercept=False)
        aaf.fit(prostate_dataset,args[1],event_col=args[2])
        aalenListPlot=list(prostate_dataset.columns.values)[2:]
        aalenPlotTemp=[]
        fig=plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,20))
        fig.suptitle('Regression in Aalen\'s Additive Model', fontsize=20)
        i=1 
        for x in aalenListPlot:
            ax = plt.subplot(6,2,i)
            xlabel('Time')
            ylabel('Cumulative hazards')
            aaf.plot( columns=[ x ], color='red',ax=ax )
            i=i+1

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)
        return fig

    printaalen('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf','rx')
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            if 'uploadAndAnalyze' in request.POST:
                printaalen('prostate1.csv','dtime','status1','age','hg','sz','sg','pf')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()    
    grid(True)

    # Store image in a string buffer
    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
    canvas.draw()
    pilImage = PIL.Image.fromstring("RGB", canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
    pilImage.save(buffer, "PNG")
    pylab.close()

    # Send buffer in a http response the the browser with the mime type image/png set
    return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), mimetype="image/png")
```

Comment: Would it be appropriate for your use case to save the generated image on disk? That way you could refactor the generation of the image to a separate function that saves the png and returns the path. Your main view (`listindex`) would invoke this function and then add the resulting path to the template context. The template then can render it within an `<img/>` tag.

Comment: ah that's what I thought too @sthzg, I already know how to send parameters to two views, thanks to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29112253/2699120) , now I don't know if it possible to overwrite the old image everytime I saved the new one